# How is "one-shot learning" implemented in the NEF/SPA?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, computational-modeling, nef, spa

In various cognitive modelling publications, "One-Shot Learning", which is just learning given very few examples, is praised as being an essential part of human cognition. For example, in "[One-Shot Learning with a Hierarchical Nonparametric Bayesian Model](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v27/salakhutdinov12a/salakhutdinov12a.pdf)" a statistical model is used to quickly develop categories given a few examples of digits from the MNIST database.

Are models built using the NEF/SPA capable of "One-Shot Learning"? Are there any examples of this being performed in a task?

Comment: I think, the chance to get an answer here is very low unless there happens to be someone from the team behind the NEF on this site. Maybe it's a better idea to ask this on their [mailing list](http://ctnsrv.uwaterloo.ca/mailman/listinfo/nengo-user) ? And maybe they can post their answer here as well or you just copy it to here.

Comment: I work in the NEF lab, which is why I usually ask the questions in the tag. This question is currently being discussed [in the forum](https://forum.nengo.ai/t/one-shot-learning-examples), at which point I will summarise the discussion here for future reference.

Comment: Ah I see. That's convenient :)